# Recursive descent parser for calculus of constructions

Tags: parsing, haskell

I implemented a type-checker and reducer of calculus of constructions in Haskell with a simple monadic parser using [Megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec). Now I want to improve it so it can recognize this syntactic shortcut:

```
∀(x:A)->B (with x not free in B)  =  A -> B
```

The grammar for this syntax is as follows:

```
<expr>
    = "(" <expr> ")"
    | <expr> <expr>
    | "λ" "(" <name> ":" <expr> ")" "→" <expr>
    | "∀" "(" <name> ":" <expr> ")" "→" <expr>
    | <expr> "→" <expr>
    | <name>
    | "*"

<name> = [_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*
```

My current parser uses this variation with left recursion eliminated (without the shortcut):

```
<expr>
    = "(" <appl> ")"
    | "λ" "(" <name> ":" <appl> ")" "→" <appl>
    | "∀" "(" <name> ":" <appl> ")" "→" <appl>
    | <name>
    | "*"

<appl> = <expr>+

<name> = [_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*
```

The previously mentioned shortcut is left-recursive. I have no idea how to convert it to a right-recursive grammar so it can be handled by a conventional recursive descent parser.

I know there exist more powerful parsing techniques that can handle left-recursive grammars, but I want to keep it right-recursive to left open the possibility of implementing a parser by hand in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has been evident after a short break. Use exactly the same trick that we did on `<appl>` and extend it as follows:

```
<expr>
    = "(" <appl> ")"
    | "λ" "(" <name> ":" <appl> ")" "→" <appl>
    | "∀" "(" <name> ":" <appl> ")" "→" <appl>
    | <name>
    | "*"

<appl> = <expr>+ ("→" <appl>)?

<name> = [_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*
```

I will leave the question open in case it helps somebody.